# In Rails, if "gem install ___" installs 6 gems total, will installing as plugin require installing the other 5 gems manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

If installing a gem using

```
gem install ______
```

actually install 6 gems, because of the dependencies, then if the gem is installed as plugin by

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/author/____.git
```

or

```
script/plugin install _____
```

then we to manually install the gem it depends on?

Does it matter if it is the later form, where it doesn't get it from github?

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about gems and dependencies, plugins are probably not the way to go. I would recommend checking out [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/). It allows you to lock your gem versions and makes it really easy to manage gem sets across multiple servers, and developers.

Comment: can't use Bundler because it is Rails 2.2.2...  it seems... or the team is not using Bundle for this Rails project

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are supposed to include their own dependencies inside them so you'll have:

```
# my_rails_project/vendor/plugins/thatfancyplugin/vendor/<their dependencies>
```

If the plugin you're looking at includes those other gems inside the repo, you'll be fine to just install the plugin. I expect it doesn't though which would require you to explicitly define the requirements in your `config/environment.rb` file.

It's for this reason that I'd recommend using it as a gem, because then you don't have to manually specify requirements that shouldn't be concerning you. A number of plugins have changed their recommended installation instructions telling people to install as a gem instead of a plugin, which is I expect mostly for this reason.